# Estimating genetic relatedness between subsamples of a population

Tags: r, genetics, genome

I have my Bed/Bim/Fam files with a large number of people (100,000+).
I would like to estimate genetic relatedness between a subgroup A and another subgroup B without having to estimate the full `(A+B) x (A+B)`. 
I just want to get an `A x B` resulting matrix.

I cannot find this option in PLink nor GCTA. Is there a way to do this with some other software? (example command or code would be very appreciated if there)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying KING:

http://people.virginia.edu/~wc9c/KING/

You could simply compute genetic relatedness between all individuals and subset for your two groups afterwards. It is really fast and should do what you want, see manual:

http://people.virginia.edu/~wc9c/KING/manual.html

For example, to compute pairwise relatedness:

```
king -b ex.bed --related
```

Where input is a PLINK binary PED file. LD pruning your SNPs prior to analysis is not necessary, as specified by the manual; however, I pruned SNPs for a cohort of 20,000 samples as the analysis with ~800,000 array genotyped SNPs took to long and didn't results in appreciable benefit in my case.

Below is procedure I used:

```
# 1. Filter for SNPs that pass all QC tests
plink --bfile input --extract good-qual.txt --make-bed --out input2
# Exclude regions of high LD
plink --bfile input2 --exclude high-LD-regions-hg19.txt --range --make-bed --out input3
# Only consider SNPs with MAF > 0.01 and genoptype missingness < 0.01.
plink --bfile input3 --maf 0.01 --geno 0.01 --make-bed --out input4
# LD prune SNPs and extract pruned SNPs
plink --bfile input4 --indep-pairwise 5000kb 5 0.1 --out input4
plink --bfile input4 --extract clsa1-b1to4-qc3.prune.in --make-bed --out input4-pruned
# Run KING, infer down to 3rd degree
king -b input4-pruned --related --degree 3 --rplot --prefix input4-pruned-related-degree3
```

Regions of high LD on GRCh37:

```
1       48287980        52287979        1
2       86088342        101041482       2
2       183174494       190174494       3
3       47524996        50024996        4
3       83417310        86917310        5
5       44464243        50464243        6
5       128972101       131972101       7
6       25392021        33392022        8
6       56892041        63942041        9
6       139958307       142458307       10
7       55225791        66555850        11
8       7962590         11962591        12
8       42880843        49837447        13
8       111930824       114930824       14
10      36959994        43679994        15
11      87860352        90860352        16
12      33108733        41713733        17
20      32536339        35066586        18
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed example Vince, so I guess there is no way to compute directly a subset and I'll have to get the full 500,000 x 500,000 matrix.

Comment: KING produces a pairwise table.